# How different is mashup from screenscraping and consuming webservices

Tags: web-services, screen-scraping, mashup

From what I understand, Mashup is aggregating data from separate sources and providing a single view.
How different is mashup when compared to screenscraping or using webservices to get data from external sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mashup = combining data

Screenscraping = one way (the hard way) to get data

Webservice = another way to get data